# why pseudo selector not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use pseudo selector with odd and even, but the selector rather select every element

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 mt10 mb10 no-padding-side p-method">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side">
    <div class="with-method">
        Paypal
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side">
    <div class="with-method">
        Wechat
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side">
    <div class="with-method">
        Alipay
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side">
    <div class="with-method">
        Mobile Money
    </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried the below variation of selector but to no success

```
 .with-method{
   margin-bottom:5px;
 }

 .test > div .with-method:nth-of-type(odd){
   background-color: yellow;
}
.test > div .with-method:nth-of-type(even){
   color:blue;
}

.with-method{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

also try select direct with the inner div like this

```
 .with-method:nth-of-type(odd){
 background-color: yellow;
}
.with-method:nth-of-type(even){
   color:blue;
}
```

but yellow added to all element rather than the ones with odd index

Comment: You are using it on the wrong level. All your `.with-method` elements are the _single and only_ child of their respective parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `nth-of-type()` only works in the context of the direct parent: in this case, the `.with-method` element is always the first (and therefore odd) child in the parent, it will always match the selector `.with-method:nth-of-type(odd)`.

If you are 100% sure that all columns only contain a single `.with-method` element, then you can apply the nth-child selector to the parents instead. Otherwise, you will need a JS-based solution to achieve what you want.

```css
.with-method {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col:nth-of-type(odd) .with-method {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col:nth-of-type(even) .with-method {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 mt10 mb10 no-padding-side p-method">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side col">
    <div class="with-method">
      Paypal
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side col">
    <div class="with-method">
      Wechat
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side col">
    <div class="with-method">
      Alipay
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 no-padding-side col">
    <div class="with-method">
      Mobile Money
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every element you have that is a member of the `with-method` class is the *first and only* child of its parent element (and is thus `odd`).

Possibly you should be targeting the elements with `.col-sm-6.col-xs-6.no-padding-side:nth-child(xxx) > .width-method`